# Error in manifest after updating to Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating Android Studio to 1.4 RC1, I got that errors in manifest.

when I hover over it I see this message:

```
<interface declaration>, <parcelable declaration>, AidlTokenType.import or AidlTokenType.package expected, got '.'
```

[image]

Is it a bug to everyone or the problem is mine.

Comment: remove .ui just  have .SignupActivity, .LoginActivity and try

Comment: I have made a completely new project and the error stand still. the problem isn't from my project.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183213

Comment: I see that issue before asking my question and it's totally different one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

humazed

please do un-inject Language/Reference from suggestion that may help you, i had same issue in few hour ago, now worked perfectly.

Comment: it works, but you need after doing that to go to:
file>>invalidate caches/restart...